# How would dimensional travel(similar to Obito's Kamui) work?

Tags: physics, alternate-worlds

I am writing a story on which several characters are able to create pocket dimensions. For example: character A does this by warping space permanently, through something akin to a programming language, on a certain object so it can house more things.
I am having a difficulty conceptualizing a sight-based application of pocket dimensions similar to Obito's Kamui(a power that possesses the ability to transport things to a separate dimension that only he can acess).
If so how would such dimension be separate from ours?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Hello @Lucas-G, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. We have some problems here. (a) You've tagged this [tag:science-based], we'll do our best, but the ideas of pocket universes and other dimensions are only *mathematical theories.* Insofar as Science knows, they don't actually exist. We don't know squat about how they'd work. (b) Which means you're asking us to help you conceptualize a work of fiction. No problem, that's what we do, but you need to bring additional details into this to help us out. I haven't the slightest idea what the word "hammerspace" means, I've never read (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... anything about an "Obito's Kamui," and so I'm having a more difficult time than you are. Per SE's rules, you're expected to bring all the relevant data into the question. You can link to things as source material, but you cannot expect anyone to follow links or, worse, actually go out and research for themselves what you're talking about. All that needs to be in your post. That will actually help both you and we as that effort will help clarify in your head what you're asking about. (c) It would help tremendously for you to (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... carefully read through our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages to understand the goals and limits of this site: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. They'll help you to avoid question closure, as this one could be for lack of details. Thanks.

Comment: @JBH, "Hammerspace" is a standard term for where something comes from when you reach behind your back and pull it out. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace This isn't just a cartoon thing, either, it's a standard method for simplifying the logistics of a story line. Usually it's a matter of not knowing where something is stored when it's off-screen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RobertRapplean While I appreciate your effort, what we need is for someone to [edit] his post to include that info in the post (preferably Lucas, who I'm trying to help understand how to use this site). Hopefully, Lucas agrees with your description (which is why I prefer the OP make the changes.)

Comment: @RobertRapplean I just read your link. Heaven help us if that's what the OP is talking about. `Further research into the exact location of Hammerspace awaits solution of a few more basic questions. Such as: "What happens when you turn a Bag of Holding inside out?" and "Why is the inside of the TARDIS only that much larger than its exterior?"` That's an indefinable narrative construct that has nothing at all to do with [tag:science-based].

Comment: @JBH, OP doesn't actually know what to ask, and that's the problem. What he really needs is a compare and contrast of the various forms of extra-dimensional spaces, so that's what I provided for him. I also provided him with avenues of research so that he can form better questions on this in the future.

Comment: I changed "science-based" to "math-based', since there is no science to extra-dimensional spaces, but they can be described with mathematics. I didn't apply the tag "mathematics" because he isn't asking about math, he just wants something that math can be applied to.

Comment: Thank you for a constructive critique of my post.

Answer (score 2):

You have to differentiate between [hammerspace](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace), dimensional bags, and dimensional travel.

Hammerspace is a storytelling concept where you ignore something if it isn't on-screen. It can be spoofed in many ways, but it's still just a matter of reaching out of sight and grabbing something, even if it's reaching behind your back. It doesn't actually translate to the written world because, in a book, everything is always off screen.

With dimensional bags, you have to define the interface and the packing algorithm. Your standard bag of holding has a "hole in space" style interface that can be expanded or gathered, defined by the loop of the opening to the bag. In some cases, the inside of the bag is a fixed-dimension cube, while in others the space is amorphous, and you're looking at more of a weight limit. Lawrence Watt-Evans has bags with infinite space, but you have to pull everything out in the reverse order that it went in. In some cases you just have to imagine what you want to pull out of it, and the bag figures it out.

Dimensional travel is different, and this is where Obito's Kamui comes in. I have characters that literally carry a weapons rack like a backpack, but just off the 4th dimension. They reach for the things by reaching off of the nominal volume. This 4d-mobility is their specific magic. Everything exists in an equivalent space to ours, just offset, so you can only fit a cubic foot of things in a cubic foot of extra-dimensional space.

You probably aught to read [Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland). It's a short read. It describes the conditions for Obito's Kamui. Imagine a perfectly flat, infinite plane, but where the people can't even *look* up, much less travel there. Obito moves things upward, so that they hang in the air on a different plane. Stuff on the nominal plane can't interact with stuff floating in air. Unfortunately, this is essentially a form of 4-D telekinesis.

Your question of "how does it connect" doesn't actually make sense. How does the space to your right connect to the space you're currently in? The only difference is that you can reach into the space to your left, and us mere humans have no 4d mobility.

In "[The Long Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Earth_(series))," Pratchett and Baxter theorize a multitude of Earths, each just a step away from our current one. This is an integer form of dimensional travel, actually closer to the Kamui. The big difference is that the other dimension is extremely similar to ours, but with no people.

Pick your model, then generalize.

Comment: Damn. That was cool. Sure I'll read the Flatland. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As a visualization model consider a piece of paper to be our 3D universe.  Tape a strip of paper by the edge to the middle and leave the other end free.

This is your pocket universe.  A path on the main piece of paper can either stay on the paper or take a detour to the small strip and leave the universe.  (This also is a good way to visualize how a Doctor Who TARDIS works - the door is where the strip connects to the main paper.)

If you want something to dissappear permanently just remove the strip - it is forever disconnected from the main universe.

The math is the same for a 3D universe just it will be 3D universes embedded a 4D space. (Well really advanced math doesn't need the embedded part - but we are just visualizing how it works.)